# How to apply a probability to a cell in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, loops, probability

Just a simple question today. If I have an m*n matrix and I want to cycle through every value in it and apply a probability based function.

Basically, if the probability is p, then each value in the matrix has p chance of having the function applied to it.

I have the loop and the function itself all worked out, but I haven't found how to actually apply the probability itself.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that you can generate the random numbers first, and then apply the other formulas.

For example:

`R = rand(m,n) < p`

Now each value of `R(row,col)` corresponds to the outcome that you need to process your original `matrix(row,col)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your data matrix:

```
>> X = reshape(1:9, 3, 3);
```

and you want to (possibly) apply the following function to every element (note how I've vectorized it, so that it can take a matrix as an argument)

```
>> f = @(x) x.^2;
```

You want to apply the function with probability *p*

```
>> p = 0.25;
```

So generate some random numbers between 0 and 1, and see which ones are less than *p*

```
>> idx = rand(3,3) < p;
```

And now apply the function to the relevant indexes

```
>> X(idx) = f(X(idx));
```

Here's your result:

```
>> X
X =
     1    16     7
     2     5    64
     3     6    81
```

Answer (score 1):

So I suggest applying your function to every cell and then setting the values to a default value based on some probability. So lets assume M is the result of applying to function to everycell:

```
default = NaN % Or 0 or whatever
p = 0.8;
M(rand(size(M)) > p) = default;
```

I think you might have to reshape m after this... not sure

```
M = reshape(M, m, n);
```